# Downloading multiple files from FTP

Tags: ftp

I was given a ftp site (ftp://ftp.example.com/) with a username and password to download some drawings.  I first tried using Filezilla, but wasn't able to do so.

```
Status: Connecting to ftp.example.com...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "Estimating@ftp.example.com" 22
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
Status: Waiting to retry...
Status: Connecting to ftp.example.com...
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "Estimating@ftp.example.com" 22
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

I am able to access the FTP using Chrome and Firefox, and could also do so using IE however have some corporate proxy server problems and must do it as ftp://USER:PASSWORD@ftp.example.com.  Problem is there are about a hundred drawings, and I don't want to download one at a time.

I then installed fireftp, however, clicking the `(Chose an account)` produces no effect.

How can I download multiple files from the FTP at once.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you have Filezilla configured to use SFTP which is a different (and secure) protocol than FTP that will only work if the server you're using is configured for it.

Check the connection that you set up in Filezilla and change it to regular FTP.

Answer (score 0):

Below is some background and useful details:

- When you connect to FTP using a browser (Chrome, Firefox, or IE), you
  provide the browser with a Uniform Resource Locator (URL) like this:
  `ftp://user:password@ftpserver/url-path`.  While this works for a
  browser, you cannot simply enter this into FTP software.
- FileZilla supports many different protocols (FTP, FTPS, SFTP) and has support for HTTP/1.1, SOCKS5, and FTP-Proxy.  One of these may work for you, but FileZilla will not automatically detect what's on the other end, so you need to configure it correctly based on what you are connecting to (assuming what you are connecting to is supported).

Observation from your log:

- The log you posted above suggests you are attempting to connect over SFTP (indicated int he log as fzSftp).  Since the connection timed-out, we can deduce that the FTP server is not hosting an SFTP listener on the specified port (port 22 is commonly used for SFTP).

Comments and suggestions:

- If you can connect with FTP software, this is likely the easiest way to download multiple files at once, so you are on the right track.  The good news is that you have eliminated SFTP as a possible protocol.  The bad news is that you still need to figure out how to configure the connection.
- At this point you can either try different options within a tool like FileZilla, until you find one that works, or you can talk to the FTP Administrator and ask them specifically how to connect using a tool like FileZilla, which would be my recommendation as it would save you some headache.

If the FTP Admin is not accessible or you just want to take a few more stabs at it, try the following in FileZilla:

- Select FTP instead of SFTP and see if you can connect that way.  Note:  FTP uses port 21 by default.
- If that doesn't work, try one of the Generic proxy methods.  Go into `Edit > Settings`, select `Generic proxy`, and try a few of the generic proxy settings.  `HTTP/1.1 using CONNECT method` is likely your best bet, but you can try them all if you like.

Again, as mentioned above, I would suggest you save yourself some frustration and go back to whoever provided you the login credentials and ask them for specific details on connecting with an FTP client, like FileZilla.  Most companies that host FTP have some kind of directions/details they can provide.